# Detecting the gesture in android

Tags: android

I am thinking of creating an android app that is able to detect what the user has written in a touch gesture. To make things clear let me give an an example.

A user touches on the screen and draws the alphabet 'A'. I want my app to be able to detect that the user has drawn an 'A'. It would be helpful if someone suggested an approach to solve the problem or any API that can be used for this purpose.